# Cloned value is getting appended to the new template value

Tags: angular6

I am new to angular. I was trying to clone a set of elements which is working fine but I am not able to get the latest value of the new cloned element when I console it or in the view.

It might be because of a variable called `temp` which is getting the cloned values. How to get the respective fields values in the console like

```
example=[{
    exp1="aaa",
    exp2="bbb",
    exp3="tea"
 },{
    exp1="ddd",
    exp2="eee",
    exp3="mango"
 }]
```

?

Please refer the below link for the working copy of the code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gvwv4g-h2sxnd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it this way

this.example.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.temp)));

Please refer the below example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gvwv4g-effowp

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy your form filled values into a new object, then pushing this new object into your array, then you can reset your object value, so the new added line will be empty.

I have edited your `input-overview-example.ts` as follow

```
import { Component , OnInit} from '@angular/core';

import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
/**
 * @title Basic Inputs
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'input-overview-example',
  styleUrls: ['input-overview-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'input-overview-example.html',
})
export class InputOverviewExample implements OnInit {
   // test Start
   foods=["mango","tea","apple"]
  example= [ ];

   temp: any;

  //test ends

 ngOnInit() {
   this.initTemp();
    this.example.push(this.temp);
  }

testAdd(){

  console.log(this.temp)
  console.log(JSON.stringify(this.example)+"-------");
  this.initTemp();
  this.example.push({
                      exp1: this.temp.exp1,
                      exp2: this.temp.exp2,
                      exp3: this.temp.exp3,
                      });

}

initTemp() {
  this.temp = {
    exp1:"",
    exp2:"",
    exp3:""
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but I wanted to use "temp" as a global variable and reduce the reassigning work to it again and again which you are doing using InitTemp() method. Example:  temp= {
    exp1:"",
    exp2:"",
    exp3:""
  }

Comment: I think you can't, because with two way data binding you will have many equals object that means many equals rows